# WebView - Sandboxing is not allowed

Tags: android, html, webview, sandbox

I have a problem with HTML file and WebView in Android Studio

The first time the site is operating normally

But when I go out and go back again, I get the following message "Sandboxing is not allowed"

HTML File :

```
<script type='text/javascript'>ch='Bein_Sports2'; ch_width=screen.width; ch_height=screen.height;</script><script type='text/javascript' src='https://arembed.com/live.js'></script>
```

JAVA code

```
String myurl = "file:///android_asset/bein"+getIntent().getStringExtra("num")+".html";
WebView view = findViewById(R.id.webView);
view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
view.getSettings().setSupportMultipleWindows(true);

String newUA= "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12) AppleWebKit/602.1.50 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/10.0 Safari/602.1.50";
view.getSettings().setUserAgentString(newUA);
view.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
view.loadUrl(myurl);
CookieSyncManager.createInstance(this);
CookieSyncManager.getInstance().startSync();
CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
cookieManager.setAcceptCookie(true);
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptThirdPartyCookies(view, true);
}
view.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        return (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE);
    }
});
```

Comment: Did you ever get around this issue?